# Covering a room with 34 carpets

Tags: mathematics, tiling, primes

There are 34 rectangular integers less than 100 which are the product of two primes. Can a room be  covered precisely (no overlaps, etc.) with the 34 rectangles that have as areas these products?

Comment: What are the properties of the room?

Comment: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/118757/find-the-carpets

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**No.**

> The total area of the rectangles is $1707= 3 \cdot 569$.  That rectangle is too narrow for the carpets of width $5$ or $7$

Comment: And if we exclude the four square rectangles and thus are left with total area 1620?

Comment: That is much harder.  You need one dimension larger than $47$, so if it works I would bet on $60 \times 27$

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tiling for the suggested alternative, using the 30 rectangles with distinct prime sides and area less than 100, to tile a 60x27 rectangle. Just brute force but I helped a bit by ordering the rectangles 'longest first'.[image]